# Python interpolate two lists with date-value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, approximation

I have two lists like `list = [[date, value], [date, value] ... [date, value]]`

And I'm trying to get interpolated lists from this two lists.

At first, I have got polynomial coeficients:

```
import numpy as np

coefficients = np.polyfit(
    np.array(values_from_x_list),np.array(values_from_y_list), polynomial_degree
)
```

Then, each value from X list I try to interpolate, like:

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval

for value in values:
    polyval(value, coefficients[::-1])
```

And I got same value like from Y lists.

Here is my output for example:

```
x_list = [
    ['2016-12-05', 2.0541010116247905e-06], ['2016-12-17', 1.786168458607079e-06], ['2017-01-10', 2.397426644056526e-06]
]

y_list = [
    ['2016-12-07', 0.323], ['2016-12-19', 0.527], ['2017-01-07', 0.693]
]

interpolated_list = [
    ['2016-12-05', 0.323], ['2016-12-17', 0.527], ['2017-01-10', 0.693]
]
```

So, and here is an example what I want (something like this values):

```
interpolated_list = [
    ['2016-12-05', 0.2xx], ['2016-12-07', 0.323], ['2016-12-17', 0.4xx],
    ['2016-12-07', 0.323], ['2017-01-07', 0.693], ['2017-01-10', 0.7xx]
]
```

**UPD**

I don't need to interpolated dates, only values. In another words I only want to change values in x_list (not dates). Dates are constants in both lists.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a date into a numerical value? If so, check out ``datetime`` ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html ). You could read in every date as a new datetime object and then create a new time axis for each date as the ``(date_i-date_0).total_seconds()``.

Comment: @alexblae I'm not sure that it is what I want. I just need to extend y_list by x_list but values in x_list must be closer to values from y_list

Comment: So you want to insert ``x_list`` into ``y_list`` and assign for the inserted elements the value from ``y_list`` for which the date is closest?

Comment: @alexblae nope, I want insert x_list into y_list but with interpolated values.

Comment: `numpy` has a version of `datetime` that is suitable for calculations, `np.datetime64`.  It will be simplest if you put dates and values in separate arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj see my UPD

Answer (score 0):

```
In [317]: x_list = [ ['2016-12-05', 2.0541010116247905e-06], ['2016-12-17', 1.786168458607079e-06], ['2017-01-10', 2.397426644056526e-06]]

In [319]: dates = np.array([i[0] for i in x_list], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [320]: values = np.array([i[1] for i in x_list])

In [321]: dates
Out[321]: array(['2016-12-05', '2016-12-17', '2017-01-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [322]: values
Out[322]: array([  2.05410101e-06,   1.78616846e-06,   2.39742664e-06])
```

The `dates` with the `[D]` unit, then are `int64` numbers:

```
In [325]: dates.view(np.int64)
Out[325]: array([17140, 17152, 17176], dtype=int64)
```

and can used in math, such as the difference between them:

```
In [326]: dates[1:]-dates[:-1]
Out[326]: array([12, 24], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

This isn't a full solution, but I think it's a step toward treating the dates as numeric values that can be used in your `polyfit`.